# How to write zero-width assertions in vim?

Tags: vim

Here is the raw material I’m working with:

```
line1=a1 abc
line2=abc
line3=aba
line4=cbc
```

i want to match lines which do not contain  character string of "abc" ,the result is :

```
line3=aba
line4=cbc
```

how can i get it in vim? maybe the expression is something such as  **(?!abc)**  in perl ,i am not sure how to write the regular expression in vim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match lines not ending with abc you could write the expression in two ways. My preferred is With very magic

```
/\v.*(abc)@!/
```

And with no very magic:

```
/.*\(abc\)\@!/
```

I recommend you to take some time to read:

```
:help magic
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Power Of G](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Power_of_g):

> Delete all lines that do not match a pattern.
>
> `:g!/<pattern>/d`

Of course, you can replace the `d` at the end to do something other than deleting the line...

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're familiar with Perl regular expressions. You will probably be interested in `:help perl-patterns` where you can Vim equivalents for common Perl regex patterns. There, you can see that for a zero-width negative look-ahead, you want `\@!`.

For other zero-width patterns, including some not listed at `:help perl-patterns`, see `:help /\@=` and following. Also useful are `\zs` and `\ze` which can avoid some more complex zero-width matches in many cases.